# Make Rhythmbox access a subfolder of MTP-drive

Tags: usb, android, rhythmbox, mtp, music-player

I am trying to sync my Rhythmbox library to an Android phone. Since the mass storage mode has been removed from Android, im fiddling around with MTP. Unlike others, it is no problem for me to access the files on the phone using the file browser. The only problem seems to be to tell Rhythmbox where to put the data. Many hints suggest putting a `.is_audio_player`-file into the root directory of the drive; however, that directory is not writable. The directory structure, as presented to Ubuntu, is

```
mtp://[usb:...]/
    Phone
          ...
    Card
          Music
          ...
```

but only the subdirectories `Phone` and `Card` are writable. Can I tell rhythmbox somehow which directory to use, without putting a file into the `mtp://[usb:...]/`-folder?

Comment: Did you find a solution?